# An exercise in politics and game theory

Tags: discussion, support

(Politics exercise) Consider a population of voters uniformly distributed along the ideological spectrum from left $(x = 0)$ to right $(x = 1)$. Each of the candidates for a single office simultaneously chooses a campaign platform (i.e. a point on the line between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$). The voters observe the candidates’ choices and then each voter votes for the candidate whose platform is closest to the voter’s position on the spectrum. If there are two candidates and they choose platforms $x_1 =0.3$ and $x_2 = 0.6$, for example, then all voters to the left of $0.45$ vote for candidate $1$ and all those to the right vote for candidate $2$, and $2$ wins with $55$ percent of the vote. Suppose that the candidates care only about being elected. If there are two candidates what is the pure strategy Nash equilibrium? If there are three candidates exhibit a pure strategy Nash equilibrium. (Assume that any two candidates that choose the same platform equally split the votes cast of that platform, and that ties among the leading vote-getters are resolved by coin flips).

My thoughts to silve the problem are the following. Before start working on the secific example i thought I cound generalize it a bit.

Say that candidate $1$ chooses platform $x_1$ and candidate $2$ chooses platform $x_2$ such that their strategies are $(x_1,x_2)\in X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Since the population of voters is uniformly distributed along the ideological spectrum, then

- If $x_1=x_2$ then the population of voters in evenly split among the candidates.
- If $x_1<x_2$ then candidate $1$ wins all the voters that are on the left of $(x_1+x_2)/2$ and candidate $2$ wins all the voters that are on the right of $(x_1+x_2)/2$. The proportion of votes of candidate  $1$, $\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1+x_2}$ and for candidate $2$, $1-\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1+x_2}$.
- If $x_1>x_2$, silimar to the second bullet.

Given this, Candidate $1$'s best response is to choose a platform $x_1$, such that it maximizes their vote share, assuming $x_2$ is fixed. And similarly, Candidate $2$'s best response is to choose a platform $x_2$, such that it maximizes their vote share, assuming $x_1$ is fixed. Finally, the the Nash equilibrium will occur when both candidates have chosen platforms such that neither has an incentive to deviate.

My questions are the following

1. My approach could solve the problem above for the given numbers?
2. How much will this change with the 3rd candidate? I believe again you have to take cases for $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$
3. Could someone explain the meaning of the last assumption? ``Assume that any two candidates that choose the same platform equally split the votes cast of that platform, and that ties among the leading vote-getters are resolved by coin flips"

Comment: Hi, meta is not for asking questions, meta is for site discussion